# Access denied, SharePoint app. Copy file to another site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

UPDATE: I understand now that by installing an app in web scope, it only gets access to the hostweb and appweb. So I tried to batchinstall the app - and now the APP works.
However, the App Part isnt available other than in the App Catalog.
Does Anyone know a way to give the App Part permissions to other site collections, or batch install the App Part so its available in other places than app catalog?

---

have this code that I'm using for downloading a file from one sitecollection, and trying to upload it to another, in sharepoint online.

I'm getting a 403 that im not allowed to upload the file. The DOWNLOAD is fine.
Does anyone have any clues?

```
var web;
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;

$(document).ready(function () {
    sharePointReady();
});

function sharePointReady() {
    hostweburl =
         decodeURIComponent(
             getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl')
     );
    appweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl')
     );

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + '/_layouts/15/';

    $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
                function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', copyAndUploadFile); }
            );
        }
    );
}

function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == param) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}

function copyAndUploadFile() {
    var targetUrl = "https://sogetiumea-my.sharepoint.com/personal/simonagren_sogetiumea_onmicrosoft_com";

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

    var fileContentUrl = "_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme003.spfont')/$value?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
    var fileTargetUrl = "_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('_catalogs/theme/15')/Files/Add(url='fontscheme003.spfont', overwrite=true)?@target='" + targetUrl + "'";




    $.ajax({
        url: "_api/contextinfo",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-url-encoded",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var digest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

            var getFileAction = {
                url: fileContentUrl,
                method: "GET",
                binaryStringResponseBody: true,
                success: function (getFileData) {
                    var results = data.body;

                    var copyFileAction = {
                        url: fileTargetUrl,
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": digest
                        },
                        contentType: "application/json;odata=vebose",
                        binaryStrinRequestBody: true,
                        body: getFileData.body,
                        success: function (copyFileData) {
                            alert("kopiering gick bra");
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(ex));
                        }

                    };
                    executor.executeAsync(copyFileAction);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(ex));

                }
            };
            executor.executeAsync(getFileAction);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(ex));

        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround of sort.

1. I added the app part to the app catalog, and used a hardcoded value to the mysite site collection (used as source for downloading/copying the file).
2. Using developer tools I copied the html for the iframe used to show the app part i n the app catalog.
3. I activated publishing on mysites root site collection.
4. I added a scripteditor webpart. Then I added the copied iframe code. Voila, now the "app part" works.

   - At first the app listens to the current user, checks if a personal site exists, else it creates it.
   - Copies as cusom spcolor file from the mysite "_catalogs/theme/15" to same folder on the current users personal site.
   - Applies the spcolor file in "Applytheme".

This is based on the idea that Vesa has done with a provider hosted app!